# Как сделать автоматическое сохранение динамических данных в кэш на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт на котором добавляются динамические данные при клике, при перезагрузки страницы данные должны оставаться, спасибо

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Есть два хороших способа: [Cookie](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#prilozhenie-funktsii-dlya-raboty-s-kuki) и [Local Storage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage)

Если раньше не работали с хранением данных на сайте то рекомендую изучить Local Storage он проще

```
// При клике вызовите
localStorage.setItem('userName', 'Alexandr');

// При загрузке страницы
var userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
if(userName){
   alert( userName );
}
```